# EXT4-fs error + ubsan array index out of bound

Tags: 22.04, filesystem, ext4

Suddenly this message started appearing every time I start my computer. When it appears, I have to restart the computer. What's the problem? Thanks

[image]

Comment: It comes from Virtualbox being installed.  While it will appear to be working fine, there's some parts of it that are not compatible with the 6.5 Kernel, so it throws errors and warnings that get logged.

Comment: @Terrance I have not installed Virtualbox. Are you sure? So what should I do now? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at it on a tiny cell phone screen.  I have seen that message many times with Vritualbox.  Looks like you should run `fsck` on that partition of `/dev/sda3` while it is unmounted.   Might need to boot to Recovery Mode.  Also, maybe the broadcom driver might need to be reinstalled.